# Unable to access active and hover attributes bootstrap tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to change the text color of a tab when on hover and active, but I am unable to change these attributes. http://jsfiddle.net/3ngv1njp/

```
 #halftabs li a :active {
                color : orange;
            }
```

This is the css I'm using, it seems pretty straightforward to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove a space before `:active` pseudo-class.

```
#halftabs li a:active {
  color: orange;
}
```

See also [CSS Pseudo-classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I saw your fiddle. Try this

```
#halftabs li a.active {
    color : orange;
}
```